# Grouping multiple interfaces into a single interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-types

I'm trying to understand interfaces in Typescript, I can't quite get them to do what I want.

```js
interface RequestData {
  [key: string]: number | string | File;
}

function makeRequest(data: RequestData) {
  // Do something with data...
}

interface UserRequestData {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  username: string;
}

function updateUser(userData: UserRequestData) {
  makeRequest(userData); // ERROR
}

// ERROR:
// Argument of type 'UserRequestData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestData'.
//   Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'UserRequestData'.ts(2345)

interface ItemRequestData {...}
interface QueryRequestData {...}
// and more interfaces...
```

I have a several smaller interfaces such as `UserRequestData`, `ItemRequestData`, `QueryRequestData` that I want to group under a larger interface `RequestData`.

Since the smaller interfaces all have string keys and certain datatypes, I'd expect to be able to type all of them using `{[key: string]: number | string | File;}`, however that does not work.

How do I modify `makeRequest`, such that it is able to accept any interface that uses strings as keys and `number | string | File` as the value type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[key: string]` in `RequestData` interface is an example of an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) . That's only represents one property and not the entire smaller interface.

If you want `makeRequest` able to accept any interface you can use [Extending Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types). Something like:

```
interface RequestData {...}

interface UserRequestData extends RequestData {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  username: string;
}
interface ItemRequestData extends RequestData {...}
interface QueryRequestData extends RequestData {...}
```